# Visual Studio 2010: What is the command to navigate between overridden methods to virtual methods (CTRL+U /CTRL+ALT+B in IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In IntelliJ IDEA, overridden methods are indicated with a blue circle and o icon at the left margin. This means, when I click on the method and press CTRL+U, IDEA can take me to the class method that's being overridden.

Is there an equivalent command in Visual Studio 2010, including extensions that make it possible to do it? I want a shortcut to navigate from a C# overridden method onto virtual method.

NEXT:

IntelliJ IDEA also indicated if a method is being overridden, and again, an appropriate icon at the left margin. This means, when I click on the method and press CTRL+ALT+B, IDEA can show me a drop-down list of methods that overridden it.

Is there an equivalent command in Visual Studio 2010, including extensions that make it possible to do it?

Comment: What does this have to do with the Java programming language?

Comment: The post is discussing IDE shortcuts and is independent of the java language so I retagged it on the OP's behalf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have this behavior if you install ReSharper. This is [documented here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Implementation.html). Bare VS 2010 does not offer such shortcuts.

Both ReSharper and IntelliJ are the products of the same company: JetBrains, located in Russia.